# Tkinter button throwing "unknown option -XXXXX" when setting options. Python 2.7

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Here is the include file

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk 

class CollapsiblePane(ttk.Frame): 
""" 
 -----USAGE----- 
collapsiblePane = CollapsiblePane(parent,  
                      expanded_text =[string], 
                      collapsed_text =[string]) 

collapsiblePane.pack() 
button = Button(collapsiblePane.frame).pack() 
"""

def __init__(self, parent, expanded_text ="Collapse <<", 
                           collapsed_text ="Expand >>"):


    ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
    # These are the class variable 
    # see a underscore in expanded_text and _collapsed_text 
    # this means these are private to class 
    self.parent = parent 
    self._expanded_text = expanded_text 
    self._collapsed_text = collapsed_text 

    # Here weight implies that it can grow it's 
    # size if extra space is available 
    # default weight is 0 
    self.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1) 

    # Tkinter variable storing integer value 
    self._variable = tk.IntVar() 

    # Checkbutton is created but will behave as Button 
    # cause in style, Button is passed 
    # main reason to do this is Button do not support 
    # variable option but checkbutton do 

    self._button.config( width=1, height=1, borderwidth = 0)
    self._button.grid(row = 0, column = 0) 

    # This wil create a seperator 
    # A separator is a line, we can also set thickness 
    self._separator = ttk.Separator(self, orient ="horizontal") 
    self._separator.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky ="we") 

    self.frame = ttk.Frame(self) 

    # This will call activate function of class 
    self._activate() 
def toggle(self): 
    """Switches the label frame to the opposite state."""
    self._variable = not self._variable 
def _activate(self): 
    if not self._variable: 

        # As soon as button is pressed it removes this widget 
        # but is not destroyed means can be displayed again 
        self.frame.grid_forget() 

        # This will change the text of the checkbutton 

        self.toggle()
    elif self._variable: 
        # increasing the frame area so new widgets 
        # could reside in this container 
        self.frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 1) 

        self.toggle()
```

Here is the program that utilizes it.

```
# Importing tkinter and ttk modules 
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *

# Importing Collapsible Pane class that we have 
# created in separate file 
from collapsiblepane import CollapsiblePane as cp 

# Making root window or parent window 
root = Tk() 
root.geometry('200x200') 

# Creating Object of Collapsible Pane Container 
# If we do not pass these strings in 
# parameter the the defalt strings will appear 
# on button that were, expand >>, collapse << 
cpane = cp(root, 'Expanded', 'Collapsed') 
cpane.grid(row = 0, column = 0) 

# Button and checkbutton, these will 
# appear in collapsible pane container 
b1 = Button(cpane.frame, text ="GFG").grid( 
            row = 1, column = 2, pady = 10) 

cb1 = Checkbutton(cpane.frame, text ="GFG").grid( 
                  row = 2, column = 3, pady = 10) 

mainloop()
```

And here's my error.

```
TclError: unknown option "-borderwidth"
```

The error comes from this line

```
    self._button.config( width=1, height=1, borderwidth = 0)
```

Which I've also tried as

```
self._button = ttk.Button(self,command = self._activate, width=1, height=1, borderwidth = 0)
```

With the same error.

I've removed the borderwidth, and then it throws the same error with width/height. I've tested the width/height/borderwidth in other instances and it works, I'm just not sure why it won't work here.

Comment: ttk buttons don't have the same options as tk buttons. The error is telling the truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using **ttk** widgets, you have to keep in mind that many of the parameters you would set separately for each **tkinter** widget are mostly managed by styles when it comes to **ttk** widgets.

If you look up the `ttk.Button` widget options ([here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Button.html)), you can easily find out which parameters can and can not be set.

In your case, you'd have to create a style for the button.

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure("TButton", borderwidth=0)
```

If you use this code, you won't have to separately declare that your button is using that style, however every other *(ttk)* button will automatically use this style too. If you want to set a style for just one button, you'd have to do something like this:

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure("b1.TButton", borderwidth=0) #you can rename b1 to anything you want
```

and then

```
b1 = Button(cpane.frame, text ="GFG", style="b1.TButton").grid( 
            row = 1, column = 2, pady = 10)
```

You can also read up on styles by yourself [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-style-layer.html).